# How do you set the default output format for a PowerShell Cmdlet?

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm creating a PowerShell Cmdlet in C# to read fields from a JSON file and output some objects. The objects are a simple POCO type:

```
public class FieldDefinition
{
    public FieldDefinition(string name, TypeCode code)
    {
        Name = name;
        Code = code;
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    public TypeCode Code { get; }
}
```

When writing the output, the entries are presented as:

```
PS ~Debug> Get-Field

Name : Session
Code : Int64

Name : Instance
Code : String
```

Ideally, I want the default presentation to be as a table:

```
PS ~Debug> Get-Field | Format-Table

Name     Code
----     ----
Session  Int64
Instance String
```

When I call commands like `Get-Process`, I am always presented with the table format. How can I make my command present its output as a table?

Comment: Funny you should mention `Get-Process`, as that's exactly [the example used in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg580992). See also `help about_Format.ps1xml`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time a command outputs a table of data, the output actually gets (invisibly) piped to the Out-Default command. This in turn pipes the data (invisibly)
to the defualt destination, which is, which by default is “out-host”, which is the terminal.

out-host formats the data into a tabular form using formating info contained in the following file:

C:\windows\systems32\windowspowershell\v1.0\DotNetTypes.format.ps1xml
(Note: DO NOT edit this file, becuase it is digitally signed. So powershell will stop working if you make the tiniest change)

It does this by looking up the xml file for the entry for the matching object (which you can find out using get-member)

All out-* commands uses the same xml file too (although write-host is an exception which is covered later).

However it is possible that a command outputs a table that does not have a pre-defined view in the xml file. In this case the out-* command
looks up a secondary xml file for formatting guidance:

C:\windows\systems32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Types.ps1xml

Reference: https://codingbee.net/tutorials/powershell/powershell-changing-a-command-outputs-default-formatting

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a format.ps1xml file that sets the layout of your output.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg574424(v=vs.85).aspx

I've done this for script modules in the past.

Examples can be found on your local machine
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0

There are a few *.ps1xml file in the above location.

Comment: Add this file where?

Comment: to your module directory and link it in your module manifest (.pds1 file)

Comment: See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878337(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Example added below

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-7 or `Get-Help format.ps1xml`

Answer (score 1):

Example of manifest file from DHCP Microsoft module:

```
        @{

        GUID = '90eaa9df-133a-450c-8728-91055cd946a1'

        Author = 'Microsoft Corporation'

        CompanyName = 'Microsoft Corporation'

        Copyright = '© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.'

        ModuleVersion = '2.0.0.0'

        PowerShellVersion = '3.0'

        ClrVersion = "4.0"

        FormatsToProcess = 'DhcpServerPsProvider.Format.ps1xml' 

        HelpInfoUri="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=285742"

        TypesToProcess = 'DhcpServerPsProvider.Types.PS1XML'    

        NestedModules = @("PS_DhcpServerAuditLog_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerDatabase_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerInDC_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerSetting_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerV4Binding_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerv4Class_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerv4DnsSetting_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerV4ExclusionRange_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerv4FailoverReplication_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerv4FailoverScope_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerv4Failover_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerv4FilterList_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerv4Filter_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerv4FreeIPAddress_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerv4Lease_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerV4OptionDefinition_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerV4OptionValue_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerv4PolicyIPRange_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerv4Policy_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerV4Reservation_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerV4SuperScopeStatistics_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerV4Scope_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerv4Statistics_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerV4Superscope_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerV6Binding_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerv6Class_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerv6DnsSetting_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerV6ExclusionRange_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerv6FreeIPAddress_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerv6Lease_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerV6OptionDefinition_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerV6OptionValue_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerV6Reservation_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerV6ScopeStatistics_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerV6Scope_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerv6StatelessStatistics_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerv6StatelessStore_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerv6Statistics_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerVersion_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServer_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerSecurityGroup_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerv4IPRecord_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerV4ScopeStatistics_v1.0.0.cdxml" , "PS_DhcpServerV4MulticastScope_v1.0.0.cdxml", "PS_DhcpServerv4MulticastExclusionRange_v1.0.0.cdxml" , "PS_DhcpServerv4MulticastLease_v1.0.0.cdxml" , "PS_DhcpServerv4MulticastScopeStatistics_v1.0.0.cdxml" , "PS_DhcpServerDnsCredential_v1.0.0.cdxml" , "DhcpServerMigration.psm1")

    FunctionsToExport = @("Add-DhcpServerInDC", "Add-DhcpServerv4Class", "Add-DhcpServerv4ExclusionRange", "Add-DhcpServerv4Failover", "Add-DhcpServerv4FailoverScope", "Add-DhcpServerv4Filter", "Add-DhcpServerv4Lease", "Add-DhcpServerv4OptionDefinition", "Add-DhcpServerv4Policy", "Add-DhcpServerv4PolicyIPRange", "Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation", "Add-DhcpServerv4Scope", "Add-DhcpServerv4Superscope", "Add-DhcpServerv6Class", "Add-DhcpServerv6ExclusionRange", "Add-DhcpServerv6Lease", "Add-DhcpServerv6OptionDefinition", "Add-DhcpServerv6Reservation", "Add-DhcpServerv6Scope", "Backup-DhcpServer", "Export-DhcpServer", "Get-DhcpServerAuditLog", "Get-DhcpServerDatabase", "Get-DhcpServerInDC", "Get-DhcpServerSetting", "Get-DhcpServerv4Binding", "Get-DhcpServerv4Class", "Get-DhcpServerv4DnsSetting", "Get-DhcpServerv4ExclusionRange", "Get-DhcpServerv4Failover", "Get-DhcpServerv4Filter", "Get-DhcpServerv4FilterList", "Get-DhcpServerv4FreeIPAddress", "Get-DhcpServerv4Lease", "Get-DhcpServerv4OptionDefinition", "Get-DhcpServerv4OptionValue", "Get-DhcpServerv4Policy", "Get-DhcpServerv4PolicyIPRange", "Get-DhcpServerv4Reservation", "Get-DhcpServerv4Scope", "Get-DhcpServerv4SuperScopeStatistics", "Get-DhcpServerv4Statistics", "Get-DhcpServerv4Superscope", "Get-DhcpServerv6Binding", "Get-DhcpServerv6Class", "Get-DhcpServerv6DnsSetting", "Get-DhcpServerv6ExclusionRange", "Get-DhcpServerv6FreeIPAddress", "Get-DhcpServerv6Lease", "Get-DhcpServerv6OptionDefinition", "Get-DhcpServerv6OptionValue", "Get-DhcpServerv6Reservation", "Get-DhcpServerv6Scope", "Get-DhcpServerv6ScopeStatistics", "Get-DhcpServerv6StatelessStatistics", "Get-DhcpServerv6StatelessStore", "Get-DhcpServerv6Statistics", "Get-DhcpServerVersion", "Import-DhcpServer", "Invoke-DhcpServerv4FailoverReplication", "Remove-DhcpServerInDC", "Remove-DhcpServerv4Class", "Remove-DhcpServerv4ExclusionRange", "Remove-DhcpServerv4Failover", "Remove-DhcpServerv4FailoverScope", "Remove-DhcpServerv4Filter", "Remove-DhcpServerv4Lease", "Remove-DhcpServerv4OptionDefinition", "Remove-DhcpServerv4OptionValue", "Remove-DhcpServerv4Policy", "Remove-DhcpServerv4PolicyIPRange", "Remove-DhcpServerv4Reservation", "Remove-DhcpServerv4Scope", "Remove-DhcpServerv4Superscope", "Remove-DhcpServerv6Class", "Remove-DhcpServerv6ExclusionRange", "Remove-DhcpServerv6Lease", "Remove-DhcpServerv6OptionDefinition", "Remove-DhcpServerv6OptionValue", "Remove-DhcpServerv6Reservation", "Remove-DhcpServerv6Scope", "Restore-DhcpServer", "Set-DhcpServerAuditLog", "Set-DhcpServerDatabase", "Set-DhcpServerSetting", "Set-DhcpServerv4Binding", "Set-DhcpServerv4Class", "Set-DhcpServerv4DnsSetting", "Set-DhcpServerv4Failover", "Set-DhcpServerv4FilterList", "Set-DhcpServerv4OptionDefinition", "Set-DhcpServerv4OptionValue", "Set-DhcpServerv4Policy", "Set-DhcpServerv4Reservation", "Set-DhcpServerv4Scope", "Set-DhcpServerv6Binding", "Set-DhcpServerv6Class", "Set-DhcpServerv6DnsSetting", "Set-DhcpServerv6OptionDefinition", "Set-DhcpServerv6OptionValue", "Set-DhcpServerv6Reservation", "Set-DhcpServerv6Scope", "Set-DhcpServerv6StatelessStore", "Add-DhcpServerSecurityGroup", "Repair-DhcpServerv4IPRecord" , "Rename-DhcpServerv4Superscope" , "Get-DhcpServerv4ScopeStatistics" , "Add-DhcpServerv4MulticastScope" , "Set-DhcpServerv4MulticastScope" , "Get-DhcpServerv4MulticastScope" , "Remove-DhcpServerv4MulticastScope" , "Get-DhcpServerv4MulticastScopeStatistics" , "Add-DhcpServerv4MulticastExclusionRange" , "Get-DhcpServerv4MulticastExclusionRange" , "Remove-DhcpServerv4MulticastExclusionRange" , "Get-DhcpServerv4MulticastLease" , "Remove-DhcpServerv4MulticastLease" , "Get-DhcpServerDnsCredential" , "Set-DhcpServerDnsCredential" , "Remove-DhcpServerDnsCredential" )

    }
```

Note:

```
FormatsToProcess = 'DhcpServerPsProvider.Format.ps1xml'
```

this links the Output template.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of the format-table.  You add a memberset to your object.

https://learn-powershell.net/2013/08/03/quick-hits-set-the-default-property-display-in-powershell-on-custom-objects/