# powershell import csv gives back 2 different solutions

Tags: powershell, csv, import-csv

[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjFjG.png)
[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qXe1.png)

as you can see with the first laptop i get a complete different solution and i don't know why they both get the exact same csv file i runned this on 2 different computers

i tried removing the quotes but another script i wrote is to add another row and they alsways have those quotes after export-csv

i hope someone can help me

the solution i want is the second one

Comment: How did you copy the csv file from the one machine to the other?

Comment: [Edit] the question and copy-paste - do not type, this is to prevent typos - the source data for review.

Comment: The quotes in a csv are there for a reason. If for instance one of the field includes the delimiter character (by default that is the comma) or if a field has leading/trailing whitespace characters or even contains newlines, then if you blindly remove the quotes you will end up with misaligned data

Comment: You don't have the same version of the cmdlet n two machines and/or the default option of output is different.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45235431/how-do-you-set-the-default-output-format-for-a-powershell-cmdlet

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Comment: Please consider entering the examples as text instead along with the content of the csv-file you are using.